# Error message when running "make" command: /usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, debian, g++, fedora

I am unable to create a working executable file by running the make command in a tree previously built on an i386 machine.  I'm getting an error message in the form of

```
me@me-desktop:~$  make
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `../.. /Lib/libProgram.a(something.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

I've been told and reassured that this program has been tested and successfully compiled on 64-bit Fedora.

I'm running a 64-bit machine

```
me@me-desktop:~$  uname -m
x86_64
```

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04

```
me@me-desktop:~$  lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS
Release:    10.04
Codename:    lucid
```

I'm using g++

```
# me@me-desktop:~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I'm also using libtool

```
# me@me-desktop:~$ libtool --version
ltmain.sh (GNU libtool) 2.2.6b
Written by Gordon Matzigkeit <gord@gnu.ai.mit.edu>, 1996
```

Any clues as to what is going wrong?

Comment: are you building from source - or are you linking against prebuilt object/library files?  If the latter - are you sure these libraries/objects are actually 64bit?

Comment: Hi fossfreedom, sorry for the newb factor... I have no idea if these are linking against "prebuilt object/library files".  There are no executable files that came with it.  How do I determine if there are "prebuilt object/library files"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a some possibilities:

- need to run ./configure before make (if copied over from 386-machine)
- need to run ./autogen.sh (if checked out from version control with no configure script given)

Comment: Thanks aquaherd, I can confirm this was copied from a 386-machine.  I will try this out once I get access to my 64-bit ubuntu at home in like 4 hours.

Comment: In this case, doing a `make clean` before `./configure` would help. Also, if an autogen.sh is present, issuing `make distclean` may force the regeneration of the configure script for x86_64.